# Check if the postcode exists in the current country on the checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, validation

I want to check if the postcode exists in the current country on the checkout page. How to implement this? or maybe someone knows a module that does it? Thanks for any help

Comment: Could you describe it in more detail? Please give us an example.

Comment: For example, customer selects Germany as country and then enter the zip code. I need to check if entered zip code exists in Germany.

Comment: Which case do you want to check? After the customer filled out the postcode in the shipping address/billing address? Or after the customer clicks next to the payment step? Or customer save the billing address? Or other cases?

Comment: When customer clicks next to the payment step

Comment: I would like just roadmap)

Comment: Great, I'll write it soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your requirements:** check if the postcode exists in the selected country on the checkout page, when the customer clicks Next go to **the payment step** from the shipping step.
In other words, that is "check if the postcode is valid in the shipping step on the checkout page".

**Solution:**

- Frontend development: Using JS to check the postcode when the customer clicks Next go to **the payment step** from the shipping step, here send an ajax to the controller to check if the postcode exists in the selected country from the backend and then throw the error message if the postcode does not exist in the selected country.
- Backend development: create a controller to handle validating the postcode for the selected country.

**More details in implementation:**
**Frontend**:
When the customer clicks Next go to the payment step in the shipping step, it calls `setShippingInformation` function which calls `validateShippingInformation`.

So you should create a JS mixin to extend `validateShippingInformation` function which is declared in `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js`.

In `validateShippingInformation` function in your JS mixin file, check if the `validateShippingInformation` function from the parent object (in `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js`) returns **true** then you writing the validation for the postcode here. **Note**: you have to take care both the postcode from **the new shipping address form** and **the selected existing shipping address** (logged-in user).

In your validate function, get current shipping address post code, country_id and send it to the controller via Ajax. And then throw the error message if the postcode does not exist in the selected country.

**Backend**:
Create a controller to validate the postcode and return response. That controller:

- implement `HttpPostActionInterface`.
- inject `Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface` into the constructor to get request params.
- inject `Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory` into the constructor to return response.
- inject `Magento\Directory\Model\Country\Postcode\ValidatorInterface` into the constructor to validate postcode for selected country.